# Whether to use settle "in" or "on"

Tags: grammar

I've been writing some flavor text for my next board game release, which is about settling a colony in/on different planets, and I am not sure if I'm using those two prepositions correctly, if I have to use always the same or if it depends on the context.

Some of the examples are:

1. This is a tough planet to settle a colony **in/on**.
2. It has the conditions we need to settle **in/on** it.
3. We will settle our colony **in/on** the icy, rocky surface.
4. We were forced to land and settle **in/on** the dark side of the planet.
5. We will settle **in/on** the sunny hemisphere.
6. There are some regions with mountains and plateaus, and the colony has settled **in/on** one of them.

Is there any formal rule about this?

Also, do you think I should use another synonym, like "establish" or similar?

Comment: Hi, I think you are mixing 2 uses of the same word… **'settle in' is an idiom meaning *to become comfortable/familiar*** (as you would in a new home or job). **the usual sci-fi trope is *colonize***…. 'Settlers' may imply a specific generation (of colonists) from a specific 'settler' time period – In US history, the govt gave incentives to certain ethnic groups willing to 'settle a territory' to claim it from native people who were being displaced (it's become a loaded term that has historic baggage). 'Settle ON a planet' is not wrong but gives a literal image, like 'settle on the couch'.

Comment: You may get better responses over on English Language & Usage: https://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: There are also questions on English Language Learners, which is good for more basic questions that non-native English speakers have. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113326/difference-between-in-and-on https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214191/what-is-the-difference-between-in-and-on

Answer (score 1):

In these examples "in" and "on" just describe the location. Just replace "settle" with another verb to see what fits best.

- This is a tough planet to **live** **on**.
- It has the conditions we need to **live** **on** it.
- We will **put** our colony **on** the icy, rocky surface.
- We were forced to land and **sleep** **on** the dark side of the planet.
- We will **live** **in/on** the sunny hemisphere.
- There are some regions with mountains and plateaus, and the colony has **flourished** **on** one of them.

I think with "hemisphere" both options are viable. And in fact "in" could work for some of the others, but it would mean something different. e.g. With a subterranean colony, you would be settling *in* (=inside) the planet.

To add to the confusion, you can also "settle in on the planet", because "settling in" is an idiom for getting comfortable/familiar, as mentioned in the comments by @wetcircuit.
And "settling on" can also mean to "decide on". So you can "settle on settling in on a planet."

Answer (score 0):

## What sounds right:

I can tell you what sounds and feels right, but I'm not an English major. This may need to migrate to [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/). If you aren't there yet and are coming down, you are going **ON** to it, but if you're already **ON** the planet, you are going **IN** to a new place. So a ship can land **ON** Plymouth rock (come down from above), but the Pilgrims settle **IN** the New World.

This is a tough planet to settle a colony **on**. *-because the colony is being placed on the planet.*

It has the conditions we need to settle **on** it. *-because the colony is being placed on the planet.*

We will settle our colony **on** the icy, rocky surface.*-because the colony is being placed on the planet.*

We were forced to land and settle **on** the dark side of the planet. *-because you are landing on the planet.*

We will settle **in** the sunny hemisphere. *-because you previously landed, and now are settling into a new place.*

There are some regions with mountains and plateaus, and the colony has settled **in** one of them. *-because the colony is being placed in a new place.*